# Which versions of the Bible do contemporary British Pentecostal churches typically use?

Tags: bible, bible-translation, pentecostalism

I am writing a novel where one of the characters is a Black British Pentecostal Christian from London.

In the interests of accuracy, I am trying to work out which version of the Bible he would be most likely to read.

I would assume it wouldn't be the KJV, and I doubt it would be the NIV, although I suppose it could be.

I appreciate that the answer to this question may be somewhat subjective/speculative, but I feel it's narrow enough in scope to be a legitimate question.

Comment: 'Pentecostal' is a term that covers a variety of denominations that have come out of the original movement. It would help if you could narrow your search down to a specific Pentecostal Church.   The United Pentecostal Church is the most conservative. Other branches include the following:
Pentecostal Church of God;
Apostolic Church (Oneness);
Assemblies of God;
Elim.

Comment: I'm curious about why not KJV? Many Pentacostals are quite conservative theologically, and some of them would even be KJV Only. On the other hand, is somewhat more open to modern changes, why not NIV? There is a British edition of it. I admittedly know little about British versions of  Pentacostalism.